# Python envio de múltiplos e-mail com anexos diferentes

Tags: python, email, automatização

Estou criando um bot em python, para envio de e-mails para algumas pessoas com anexo diferentes, o código está assim:

```
    import win32com.client as win32
    import time
    import os
    
    #Informações do e-mail
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = 'test@outlook.com.br'
    
   #Percorre o diretório de anexos
for attachment in  os.listdir(r"pasta_anexos"):
      #Agrengando os arquivos da pasta a uma string
      file = (os.path.join(r"pasta_anexos",str(attachment)))       
      if str(file).endswith('test1.txt'):
          #Anexando test1.txt
          mail.Attachments.Add(file)        
          #Percorrendo novamente o diretorio, para nexar o segundo arquivo
          for attachment2 in os.listdir(r"pasta_anexo"):
              #Agrengando os arquivos da pasta a uma string
              file2 = (os.path.join(r"pasta_anexo",str(attachment2))) 
              if str(attachment2).endswith("test2.txt"):
                  #Anexando test2.txt
                  mail.Attachments.Add(file2)
          #informações finais do e-mail, para quem e assunto
          mail.To = 'test@outlook.com'
          mail.Subject = "Empresa X " + attachment
          mail.display()
          time.sleep(5)
          mail.Send()
          break
              
print('------------------ Primeiro e-mail ------------------')
```

Atualmente estou enviando um e-mail com dois anexos, mas precisaria enviar mais um com dois anexos diferentes, no primeiro e-mail vai dois arquivos test1.txt e test2.text, no segundo iria test3.txt e test4.text, mas quando tento colocar outro For o spyder da erro que não achou o segundo o test3.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você cria o objeto "email" na linha `mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)` - é só colocar essa linha e as seguintes dentro do `for` - para criar e enviar um e-mail para cada arquivo.

Você não falou que precisa enviar os arquivos para emails diferentes, mas não disse como vai saber esses e-mails. Se forem baseados no nome do arquivo, dá para fazer um dicionário, por exemplo, mapeando cada extensão de arquivo para um endereço  -
ou se forem endereços em sequência, poderia usar a chamada  `zip` no `for` para ter um endereço de e-mail diferente, junto com um arquivo diferente em cada chamada do `for` - mas isso basicamente vai juntar pares aleatórios de arquivos e emails, dificilmente é o que você gostaria na vida real.

De qualquer forma, pra mandar 4 e-mails diferentes, com cada um com um arquivo, e mudando o acesso a arquivos para usar a `pathlib` - o novo jeito do Python de acessar pastas e arquivos, fica assim:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import win32com.client as win32
import time
import os

#Informações do e-mail
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

folder = Path(r"pasta_de_anexos")

#leitura documentos em anexo
for attachment in folder.iterdir():
    #envio de e-mail
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = 'test@gmail.com.br'
    mail.HTMLBody = "<p>Olá,</p><p>Segue documentos em anexo.</p><p>Atenciosamente.</p>"
    mail.Attachments.Add(str(attachment))
    # coloca o nome do arquivo, sem a extnsão, como endereço do email antes do "@"
    mail.To = f'{attachment.stem}@gmail.com.br'
    mail.Subject = str(attachment)
    mail.display()
    time.sleep(5)
    mail.Send()
```

Usando o pathlib.Path nãp é mais necessário ficar chamando `os.path.join` -
por outro lado, para tratar o caminho do aquivo como uma string, precisa
fazer a chamada `str(...)` como fiz acima.

Além disso, o jeito que você estava tentando testar o nome do arquivo na linha
do "if" era essencialmente aleatório - você foi jogando coisas sem entender
o que estava fazendo e esperando que funcionasse: em programação nada funciona
assim.

Python ficou famoso por ser fácil de aprender há mais de 15 anos
atrás por causa de uma funcionalidade que hoje as pessoas
não percebem que existe, talvez por que os
cursos e documentação não deem enfase: há o modo interativo
onde você pode testar as coisas.

Use o Python no terminal, no app `idle`, ou embutido na IDE
que você está usando, se estiver usando alguma para testar
as coisas direto - vendo o resultado, antes de
tentar por no programa.

Se entrar no Python e chamar o método `.startswith` de uma
string dá pra entender como ele funciona, e não
vai ficar tentando colocar "=="

```py
In [33]: "teste23".startswith("teste")                                                   
Out[33]: True

In [34]: "tosto23".startswith("teste")                                                   
Out[34]: False
```

Fazer isso também vai te deixar mais familiarizado com `for`, `if` e outros
comandos e chamadas básicas - quando for colocar no programa,
você já vai te tentado, de jeitos certos e errados umas 10, 20 vezes
no modo interativo e vai saber como funciona. É muito mais tranquilo
do que não ter ideia de como é pra ser no código, e aí rodar e ver uma
mensagem de erro e ficar tentando adivinhar o que o erro
quer dizer.

Comment: Sobre os emails, só para citar, test1 deve ser enviado ao test1@gmail.com, test2 para o test2@gmail.com, eu estava pensando em colocar cada e-mail dentro do if

Comment: Nao = a[i é só extrair o nome do destinatário do e-mail do próprio nome do arquivo. Se o nome do arquivo fosse uma string, como no seu código, era só fazer `.split('.')[0]` - com a pathlib é só usar o atributo "stem" (o nome do arquivo sem a extensão) - vou atualizar acima